# Multiple buttons Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, button, raspberry-pi, gpio

I'm completely new to python and have a problem. I'm working on a project for school with the Raspberry Pi and have trouble reading two buttons at once. Both buttons work but I dont know how I can get input from both at the same time. I only managed to read button 1 first and then button 2 couldn't even read them more then once. My question is: How can I manage to read them in any order and multiple times?

Comment: You can use either seperate thread to read the states of the buttons or nest two ifs together. I could post you a solution once I get home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. First you must declare the GPIO, importing relevant GPIO library

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

#Substitute 24 and 25 for whatever pins your push buttons are connected to.
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

#Then assign these buttons to the variables
Button_1 = GPIO.input(24)
Button_2 = GPIO.input(25)

while True:
    if Button_1 == False and Button_2 == False:
        print('Both buttons are pressed')
        time.sleep(0.2)
```

This code works, so please ask questions if you have any problems.